# How to INSERT/SELECT data from MySQL to Excel/VBA?

Tags: mysql, excel, vba

I'm trying to extract data from MySQL to Excel. I saw a lot of tutorials but I get the same error all the time.

Here is my code:

```vb
Sub consultdate()

Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim server_name As String
Dim database_name As String
Dim user_id As String
Dim password As String

Dim i As Long
Dim sqlstr As String
Dim table1 As String, table2 As String
Dim field1 As String, field2 As String
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim vtype As Variant

server_name = "localhost"
database_name = "controle_fin"
user_id = "root"
password = "userpassword"

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.Open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}" _
& ";SERVER=" & server_name _
& ";DATABASE=" & database_name _
& ";UID=" & user_id _
& ";PWD=" & password _
& ";OPTION=16427"

table1 = "classe"

GoTo skipextract
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
sqlstr = "SELECT * FROM " & table1
rs.Open sqlstr, conn, adOpenStatic
Planilha1.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs
skipextract:

On Error Resume Next
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
conn.Close
Set conn = Nothing
On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Error that I got:

> "ODBC Error. Data Source Name Not Found and No Default Driver Specified"

Comment: are you going from mysql to excel or viceversa? title says the opposite of the question

Comment: Is the error on the `.open` line?  Looking at this https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/ is there a need to specify the driver?

Comment: Are you sure your database is running?

Comment: 1. Not sure if "localhost" is going to resolve properly. Replace it with 127.0.0.1 (or your localhost ip setup) for testing at least. 2. Make sure you have the MySQL ODBC 3.51 installed. Believe you can quickly check this by going to Start -> ODBC Connections and hitting NEW. See if its in that list.

Comment: Why do you have `GoTo skipextract` before the execution of your Connection and execution of your SQL Statement?  This doesnt address the OP's question, but just an observation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, this error is due to the following reasons:

1. **Simple Misspelling**: ODBC driver names must be exactly spelled correctly and fully including special characters. To see all ODBC drivers, open up PowerShell window and type: `Get-OdbcDriver | Format-Table name, platform -AutoSize` to output a table similar to below:

   ```
   name                                                   platform
   ----                                                   --------
   Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)                        32-bit
   Microsoft dBase Driver (*.dbf)                         32-bit
   Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)                         32-bit
   Microsoft ODBC for Oracle                              32-bit
   SQL Server                                             32-bit
   SQL Server Native Client 11.0                          32-bit
   ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server                          32-bit
   SQL Server                                             64-bit
   Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)               64-bit
   Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb) 64-bit
   Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)            64-bit
   SQL Server Native Client 11.0                          64-bit
   PostgreSQL ANSI(x64)                                   64-bit
   PostgreSQL Unicode(x64)                                64-bit
   ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server                          64-bit
   Microsoft Access dBASE Driver (*.dbf, *.ndx, *.mdx)    64-bit
   ...
   ```
2. **Incompatible 32/64 bit architectures**: Whatever ODBC driver you connect to must maintain same bit architecture as your MS Office version. If you run 32-bit Office, only 32-bit drivers are available (indicated under platform in step 1 output). Similarly goes for 64-bit. To verify which Office bit version you have installed on Windows and Mac, see [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/about-office-what-version-of-office-am-i-using-932788b8-a3ce-44bf-bb09-e334518b8b19).
3. **Permissions issue**: While drivers are available, they may not be accessible to current user or group at file and/or folder level. This tends to be more an issue on *Unix systems (Linux/Mac) and not Windows which requires `chmod` or `chown` handling. For Windows, adjust properties of file or folder in Explorer for read/write/execute permissions.